# Building BlackBerry 10 native application package from command line

Tags: blackberry-10, blackberry-ndk

I have created a native `HelloWorld` application for `BlackBerry 10` using `BB NDK 10.0.9` and running it inside a simulator. I use `Momentics IDE` and can easily compile and deploy my application.

However, i want to setup an automated build process from the command line. I was able to compile ELF binary using `makefile`. But i am stuck in creation of `.bar` file.

I try to build `.bar` with the command:

```
blackberry-airpackager.bat -package HelloWorld2.bar application.xml
```

but the target `.bar` does not contain my native binary.

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a special packager for native applications: `blackberry-nativepackager`

This code did the trick:

```
blackberry-nativepackager.bat -package HelloWorld2.bar bar-descriptor.xml
```

And yet another configuration was added to `bar-descriptor.xml` besides the simulator:

```
<configuration id="com.qnx.qcc.toolChain.2121420202" name="Device-Release">
   <platformArchitecture>armle-v7</platformArchitecture>
   <asset path="arm/o.le-v7/HelloWorld" entry="true" type="Qnx/Elf">HelloWorld</asset>
</configuration>
```

Comment: I'm trying to repackage a Unity game after some post modifications:  When I run blackberry-nativepackager on mac I get: "Error: Attribute Entry-Point: file cannot be found in the list of packaged files: Release/BB10Player"